# Originally not a movie

Tags: word, knowledge, visual, rebus, movies

Can you tell what movie these images together represents? (the answer is a 5-letter noun)

---

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These images represent the movie:

> [**Evita** (1996)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evita_(1996_film))

As they resolve as:

> A + [LAN](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network) = ALAN
>  MAD *ON* A = MADONNA
>  ANT *ON* IO = ANTONIO

These are:

> The first names of the director, **Alan Parker**, and two of its stars: **Madonna** and **Antonio Banderas**.
>
>  NB This is indeed 'originally not a movie' (as per the title) as it is based on a 1976 concept album and a 1978 musical by Andrew Lloyd Webber and Tim Rice.

Comment: Correct ofc, well done